# Split string based on byte length in golang

Tags: http, go, http-headers

The http request header has a 4k length limit.
I want to split the string which I want to include in the header based on this limit.
Should I use `[]byte(str)` to split first then convert back to string using `string([]byte)` for each split part? 
Is there any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Go, a string is really just a sequence of bytes, and [indexing a string produces bytes](https://blog.golang.org/strings). So you could simply split your string into substrings by slicing it into 4kB substrings.

**However**, since UTF-8 characters can span multiple bytes, there is the chance that you will split in the middle of a character sequence. This isn't a problem if the split strings will always be joined together again in the same order at the other end before decoding, but if you try to decode each individually, you might end up with invalid leading or trailing byte sequences. If you want to guard against this, you could use the `unicode/utf8` package to check that you are splitting on a valid leading byte, like this:

```
package httputil

import "unicode/utf8"

const maxLen = 4096

func SplitHeader(longString string) []string {
    splits := []string{}

    var l, r int
    for l, r = 0, maxLen; r < len(longString); l, r = r, r+maxLen {
        for !utf8.RuneStart(longString[r]) {
            r--
        }
        splits = append(splits, longString[l:r])
    }
    splits = append(splits, longString[l:])
    return splits
}
```

Slicing the string directly is more efficient than converting to `[]byte` and back because, since a `string` is immutable and a `[]byte` isn't, the data must be copied to new memory upon conversion, taking O(n) time (both ways!), whereas slicing a string simply returns a new string header backed by the same array as the original (taking constant time).

Comment: I wrote a benchmark to prove you wrong, but I was proven wrong, string slicing operations were nearly 5000ns/op faster than bytes slicing operations.

Comment: Now I'm curious about why it was faster! I would assume slicing a `string` and slicing a `[]byte` should take about the same amount of time, since in either case you are just constructing a new slice header referencing an existing underlying array. It's converting between the two that should be inefficient, since it has to copy the entire range. Did you include conversions in your benchmark?

Comment: Turns out that the `string` header differs slightly from a normal slice header; it doesn't include a `cap` field, because you can't grow a `string` beyond it's length by reslicing it. So it is in fact nominally more efficient to compute a new `string` header than a new slice header! See [type stringStruct](https://golang.org/src/runtime/string.go) in the Go source code.

Comment: Here is the [main](https://play.golang.org/p/MJJPW8kIFP0) program. and here is the [benchmark](https://play.golang.org/p/VHeqPhTCGG2). Yeah slice header is different from that of string, maybe it's also because of other additional checks for capacity, as it can be set different for different slices.